# convert composite java object to CSV

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, org.json

I have an object, say Response.java that looks like the following:

```
class Response
{
   private User user;  // has firstName, lastName, age etc.
   private Address address; // has city, state, country etc.
   private OrderInfo orderInfo;  // has orderNumber, orderDate etc.

   // constuctors, getters/setters follow

}
```

I need to convert a List of these objects into csv, so my end goal is something like:

```
firstName, lastName, age, city, state, country, latitude, orderNumber, orderDate
john, doe, 25, dallas, tx, usa, somelat, 101, 08/17/2015
jane, doe, 21, atlant, ga, usa, somelat, 102, 08/15/2015
```

I tried to use two libraries - jackson (csv dataformat), org.json (JsonArray), but i couldn't get the desired result.

This is my jackson csv code:

```
Response response = getResponse();
final CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
final CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Response.class);
final String csv = mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(response);
```

With Jackson, i am getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: CSV generator does not support Object values for properties
```

Is there a way to convert the composite object into csv in the way i need (just the fields without the json like grouping)?

Comment: Are you using the Jackson CSV library? If not, details are here on how to implement: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv

Comment: Did you try overridng the toString method of Response class? I think by using it you can get the desired result.

Comment: We don't really need to see the bean class.  We need to see how you're using Jackson to perform the serialization.  It's producing JSON, not CSV.

Comment: @jgitter - I've updated my question with my jackson code and jackson error message (The json output was necause i also tried to do shemaFor(json)

Comment: @ColimMc - yes, i am using jackson csv library

Comment: @Raj Sharma - yes, the toString() is overriden to print the values as you implied,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I ran similar code that you are using in a test project and it looks like you will need to use @JsonUnwrapped on all your objects (User, Address, and OrderInfo).

Jackson CSV doesn't support objects as properties which is why you got that exception. Here is the issue on Github: [Jackson CSV Object properties issue](http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues/9)

Here is sample code I used to verify this:

```
Test response = new Test();
response.setNum(1);
Stub s = new Stub();
s.setAge("12");
s.setName("Colin");
response.setS(s);
final CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
final CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Test.class);
final String csv = mapper.writer(schema.withUseHeader(true)).writeValueAsString(response);
System.out.println(csv);
```

Output from the above code was the following:

```
num,age,name
1,12,Colin
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the issue, it worked with @JsonUnwrapped.